# Why its possible to use an obect type for a rest parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
export type FnParamsToArrayParams<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args2: { [K in keyof A]: Array<A[K]> }) => R
  : never
```

Why can ...args2 be an object type?
Normally Typescript says rest must be an array, which makes sense.
And somehow typescrpt also perservers the argument names of ...args but how is that possible if args must be an array?
Can someone explain plase or post me a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Array themselves are objects.

```
// true
type Case = unknown[] extends object ? true : false
```

`object` is a type for any non-primitive type and arrays can be mapped using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as well:

```
type Mapped<T extends readonly number[]> = { [K in keyof T]: `${T[K]}-str` };

// type Result = readonly ["1-str", "2-str", "3-str"]
type Result = Mapped<Arr>;
```

Since your inferred parameter `A` is used at `...args: A`, the compiler infers its type as array  and in the mapped type you are basically mapping through the arrays, just modifying the values, thus you get the array at the end and no error.

Comment: Relevant docs for [mapped types over arrays/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays)